# export function scoping confusion es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I came across these 2 kind of syntax doing export. Says I have a file call actions.js and app.js

**The first one look like this**

in actions.js

```
export function addTodo() {}
export function deleteTodo() {}
and in app.js I have

import { addTodo, deleteTodo } from './actions.js'
addTodo() //call method
```

**The second style of doing this wrap every function to an object**

in action.js

```
const actions = {
   addTodo: function() {}
   delete: function() {}
}
export default actions
```

in app.js

```
import actions from './actions'
actions.addTodo() // call method
```

Both of them do the same thing? Is there any differences using those 2? I prefer the first one as I can import specified function out of actions.js. Is there any scoping leak using approach one? What's your preference?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two styles is that the first style can still have a default export. You can have the [two named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports) and a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export) as well. All other exports from the second style will need to be named.